# Setup for server side for application which need easy acces to data source

Tags: google-app-engine, architecture

I need to make a couple of mobile applications which will all access a shared online resource using e.g. REST API.

What is the cheapest/easiest setup for the server side resource?
The server should store data as either xml/json/sqlite and expose an API to access this data, preferably in a secure manner.

Is Google App Engine appropriate? Any others?

What would be a recommended way to implement?

What I want to do is to have a database online (not important which format - content will not bee too big, ~5000 records with around 5-10 text fields each), have a simple management console for editing this content and then let mobile devices connect in order to check if they have the latest data and update if required.
The data should not be publicly available but key may be hardcoded into device applications.

Comment: App Engine will work fine - as will every other webapp hosting service. Did you have a specific question about how to implement it?

Comment: Thanks - yes added recommendation for implementation to question.

Comment: It's still too vague for us to be able to provide useful objective answers.

Comment: If the key is hardcoded into the devices application the data eventually will be publicly available.

Comment: Yes, but the data is not secret in any way - just want there to be a very simple mechanism for authentication without the app user actually having to type in credentials. It would also be ok for data to be public I guess as long as modifying is left only to administrator.